# AsyncIO task loops not performing all tasks at the same time inside threads

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

I am trying to execute some HTTP requests on 50000+ items in a loop and i want to do that as quickly as possible. so my reasoning is to divide the 50k items (number from 1 to 50k) to chunks of 100 and then execute 100 process on those numbers (involves 3 HTTP requests that run synchronously) in a separate thread.
so i ended up with about 500 threads running. i tried to log each time a process is executed on one number and the logs are not as asynchronous and fast as i expect. what i perceived is that even though having 500 threads running at the same time with 100 task asynciO loop running in each of them, i don't get that fast logs or even the totality of requests that should be launching as it hangs every 100 or even less logs.

here is my code :

```py
    itemsLength = 50000

    limiter = 50
    allfinalItems = []
    allThreads = []
    i = 0
    while i < (itemsLength / limiter):
        try:
            thread = threading.Thread(target=runLoop, args=[list(range(i*limiter, itemsLength if ((i+1)*limiter > itemsLength) else (i+1)*limiter)), allfinalItems], daemon=True)
            thread.start()
            allThreads.append(thread)
            i += 1
        except Exception as e:
            print("error when running process")
            i += 1
            print(e)

    print("spawned threads : "+str(len(allThreads)))
    for thread in allThreads:
        thread.join()

#i do have other processing for the finalItems list after this
```

the runLoop method :

```py
def runLoop(ItemsList, finishPairList):
    print("got chunk list size : "+str(len(ItemsList))+" from : "+ str(ItemsList[0]))
    asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
    eventLoop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    taskList = []
    for item in ItemsList:
        taskList.append(eventLoop.create_task(getItemInfo(itemNumber=item, allFinishedItems=finishPairList))
    eventLoop.run_forever()

    for f in taskList:
        f.cancel()
```

the getItemInfo method is the one that does the 3 requests per item, this function is an async function but doesn't await anything inside of it. it uses an sdk that awaits requests on its own.

```py
async def getItemInfo(itemNumber, allFinishedItems):
    print("logging for item number : "+str(itemNumber))
    data = externalSDK.getDataAsynchronously(itemNumber)
    data2 = externalSDK.getDataAsynchronously(data)
    data3 = externalSDK.getDataAsynchronously(data2)
    allFinishedItems.append(data3)
```

If my assumptions are correct, this script should launch 500 threads and within each instantly launch 100 externalSDK requests upon starting the thread and then wait for the requests to finish. what happens according to the print logs is that some number requests would launch and then the script will hang for 10 seconds and resume with some more requests. it seems as it in every thread, there is a single getItemInfo method being called at a time.

is there a thing I am doing wrong here? is it because my `getItemInfo` method is not properly an async function? or is it because ima running it on low-end hardware ?

Comment: running 500 threads at the same time doesn't have to make it faster - you have only one CPU which can run ~4 processes at the same time - and it has to runs other processes in system.

Comment: better would be to use Pool with 4 worker and send all urls and it will split it to workers. It will always runs only 4 urls and it doesn't have to delete and recreate threads.

Comment: async doesn't run functions at the same time but when one task uses file or network connection then it may switch to other process - but it would better use use async function for connection. There is even [httpx](https://www.python-httpx.org/) which already use async in request

Comment: threads in Python also doesn't works at the same time because Python has GIL which blocks threads - only `multiprocessing` may runs processes at the same

Comment: @furas how do you see I divide my 50k items processing then ?